# the best way to get access

Tags: ios, global

I've got one variable and I need this variable during the whole programm. Now code is the next:
.h file

```
extern RequestParams* newUser;
```

.m file

```
RequestParams* newUser;
```

But it works bad. Information doesn't get to this variable.
What is the best way to solve this problem? 
Thank you.

Comment: You need to import the header file (the one that has `extern RequestParams* newUser;`) into every .m file that wishes to access the variable.

Answer (score 2):

**You will have to use `NSUserDefault` or `Singleton` to handle the values of varaiables accross various Controllers.**

These both are used in such a scenario where you need to maintain and access the variable values across multiple View Controllers. You can opt for either one based on your choice.
`NSUserDefault` can store multiple key-value pairs that are accessible globally throughout the app. Singleton helps you create a object / variable which is static and hence no other instance of it is created afterwards. Only a single instance is retained throughout the app.

The following links might help you.

[Singleton Tutorial](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/)

[Another Singleton Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795997/global-variable-nsmuteablearray-using-singleton-class)

[NSUserDefault Tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-nsuserdefaults--mobile-6039)

[Another NSUserDefault Tutorial](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/quick-tips/storing-data-with-nsuserdefaults/)

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

If you required only in you program then you can create it as singleton

```
//  constants.h

+ (RequestParams*) newUser;

//  constants.m

+ (RequestParams*) newUser{ 

    static RequestParams* instance = nil;

    if (instance == nil) {
        // initiate your instance here;
    }
    return instance;
}

// you can Use it where you required 

[constants newUser];
```

If you you want to keep to when application is closed then you need to use NSUserDefault to save it.

If this help you then you can accept it as solution.