# Retrieving array of custom objects from UserDefaults using NSKeyedUnarchiever in swift

Tags: swift

I have saved an array of custom objects that conforms to `NSCoding` protocol in `UserDefaults` using `NSKeyedArchiver`. But when I try to retrieve it using NSKeyedUnarchiver, i get runtime errors from Xcode. I have tried initialising `NSArray` using unarchived data but it also failed. My guess is that while unarchiving swift doesn't understand custom elements of this array. How shall I do it?

This is how I archived array of custom objects

```
static func saveCategoryList(_ categoryList : [Category]!) -> Void{
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let categoryListData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: categoryList)
        userDefaults.set(categoryListData, forKey: Constants.CategoryList)
        userDefaults.synchronize()
    }
```

I get error like the attached screenshot in runtime. I am quite sure I am not doing it right. How can get my desired result? [image]

Comment: What you have tried will be helpful for quick answer and Also need to describe error that your are got.

Comment: Why are you creating NSArray there ? You have declared Array (swift array of Category)

Comment: Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46402965/4601900

Comment: @JonSnow thanks a lot. It was a stupid thing to do. Going through learning curve of swift. :-)

Comment: Good luck :) keep learning

Comment: `categoryList = userDefaults.data(forKey: Constants.CategoryList) as?  [Category] ?? []`